# Finding out rows corresponding to empty cells in columns in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on an Excel sheet with 15k rows. I need to find out empty cells in a particular column and output the row corresponding containing the empty cell. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  What have you tried?  Please show what you've already done.

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried. If you need the rows of all blanks, this seems like an array or VBA solution, but I may be misinterpreting your question.

Comment: @jbarker2160 Being a newbie to Excel and after googling for some time, I found that I can use =COUNTBLANK(range) and ISBLANK().

Answer (score 2):

With data in column **A** cells **A1** through **A24**, in cell **B1** enter the *array formula*:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$24="",ROW($A$1:$A$24)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$24))+1),ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

and copy down.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Here is a sample:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the column of relevance is A, then in some other column, copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),ROW(),"")
```

If you want a copy of those rows somewhere, filter the added column for **non**-blank values and copy/paste what is visible.